# Objective-C different syntaxes question

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, syntax

I'm learning Objective-C at the moment so bear with me.

As I understand the general syntax (except when using properties) when coding Objective-C looks something like this:

```
[object method];
[object methodWithArgument:1 arg2:2];
```

Now to my confusion when reading upon file input/output for iOS devices, the example tells me to use a method to get the Application's documents folder:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first is Objective C syntax for calling **methods**

The second snippet uses C syntax for calling **functions**.

Objective C is a superset of C

Comment: What would be the differences between the two?

Answer (score 0):

The first syntax is for calling member methods of a class, the second is for invoking standalone functions.  Objective-c is a superset of C meaning it has all of the features of C (including functions) along with the OO features of classes and the like